# How to get the permission in NDK

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I am new to Android NDK and I have to use OpenCV in Android.

I tried to ran the NDK ahead , but these errors happened. Maybe I have no permission to use the file" /obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_contrib.a",How can I get the permission? And can the next error be OK when the first error is solved?
My workspace OS is Windows7.

```
$ NDK-build
```

SharedLibrary  : libImgFun.so
D:/Android/android-ndk-r7b-windows/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libopencv_contrib.a: No such file: Permission denied

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/cygdrive/d/Android/android-ndk-r7b-windows/android-ndk-r7b/build/core/build-binary.mk:314: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/libImgFun.so' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libImgFun.so] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows 7.  I was able to just use chmod to set the permissions manually, and then it worked.  My best guess is that this is a bug with how Cygwin, Windows, and the build process interact.

- Open a console window
- `> bash`
- `> cd /cygdrive/<driveletter>/<wherever your project is>/obj/local/armeabi`
- `> chmod 777 ./*`